# How prove $\int_{0}^{1}F(x)dx\le \int_{0}^{a}G(x)dx$

Tags: integration, integral-inequality

if $G$ and $F$ are integrable,$a>0,G(x)\ge F(x)\ge 0$,and
$$\int_{0}^{1}xF(x)dx=\int_{0}^{a}xG(x)dx$$
show that
$$\int_{0}^{1}F(x)dx\le \int_{0}^{a}G(x)dx$$
let$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt,G(x)=\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt$$
by parts:we have
$$\int_{0}^{1}F(x)dx=xF(x)|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}xdF(x)=F(1)-\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{a}G(x)dx=xG(x)|_{0}^{a}-\int_{0}^{a}xg(x)dx=G(a)-\int_{0}^{a}xg(x)dx$$
then follwing how can works?
This problem from $MM$ (Mathematics Magazine) problem $622$,Thank you everone

Comment: What happens if you try integration by parts?

Comment: use integration by parts,I think this maybe can't works,Thank you

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match MSE quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Comment: yes,I have edit.Thank you  @EricNaslund

Comment: @math110: +1, Looks good to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J(x)=\int_0^xF(t)dt$ and $K(x)=\int_0^xG(t)dt$. Since $0\le F\le G$, $J$ and $K$
are increasing, and $$J(x)\le K(y),\quad\forall\  0\le x\le y.\tag{1}$$
We want to show $J(1)\le K(a)$. From $(1)$ we know that when $a\ge 1$, there is nothing to prove, so let us assume that $0<a<1$. On the one hand, due to integration by parts,
$$J(1)-\int_0^1 J(x)dx=\int_0^1xF(x)dx=\int_0^axG(x)dx=aK(a)-\int_0^a K(x)dx.\tag{2}$$
On the other hand, by $(1)$ and noting that $J$ is increasing,
$$\int_0^1 J(x)dx-\int_0^a K(x)dx\le \int_a^1 J(x)dx\le (1-a)J(1). \tag{3}$$
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$, it follows that $J(1)\le K(a)$.

Comment: nice!Thank you Landscape.

Comment: @math110: You are welcome!